# How to get mageinferno/magento2-docker-compose setup to install an extension?

Tags: magento, magento2

Using the docker compose playbook [here](https://github.com/mageinferno/magento2-docker-compose), I cannot figure how to then use the admin panel to install an extension.

We have the `auth.json` file present in our user's `~/.compose/auth.json` file, and is mounted in the proper container as suggested by the README. However it's not clear how to run the setup container with the `M2SETUP_USE_ARCHIVE` env variable set to false. Doing so fails always.

So far, the only thing we got to work is a Magento 2.1 instance, but the Admin panel seems to be missing functionality (The Components Manager is missing from the System tab for example).

How to get that setup to work properly? What's the best way to have a clean Magento instance with extension support to play with?